# Vue 3 + Vee-Validate handleSubmit not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm using the save function on button click using handleSubmit but on click it doesn't work, as if I'm not pressing the button, can anyone tell me what it could be?

```
const schema = yup.object({
    roleName: yup.string().min(4).required()
});

const { errors, handleSubmit, setValues } = useForm({
    validationSchema: schema
})

const save = handleSubmit(values => {   // button click save function
    console.log(values)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In you schema object, the property roleName, need to be the same name of your v-model input.

```
<input v-model="textInput" label="Email:" />

const schema = yup.object({
    textInput: yup.string().min(4).required()
});
```